# Composition of uniformly continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

[Composition of uniformly continuous functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661268/composition-of-uniformly-continuous-functions)

I have seen many posts that seem to suggest that the composition of uniformly continuous functions is necessarily uniformly continuous(on R). However I'm pretty sure this is wrong and I'm hoping we can get a concrete answer. I think I have a counter example. Considering the set $[0,\infty)$, let $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=-x$ then $fg(x)=e^x$ is not uniformly continuous but $f$ and $g$ are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a counter example, since $g\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr)=(-\infty,0]$ and $f$ is *not* uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: If the set in question is $A$ (rather than that interval), does that mean we must have $g: A\rightarrow A$ to consider $fg$ then? Because in that case the theorem is obviously true.

Comment: No. We have to have a function $\colon A\longrightarrow B$ and a function $g\colon B\longrightarrow\Bbb R$, with $A,B\subset\Bbb R$.

Comment: Is there something missing from the comment? We apply g to X, then f, so shouldnt it be $g:A\rightarrow B$ and $f:B\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $B, A \subset R$ and both uniformly continuous on their domains. (Subsets not required to be proper, don't know how to latex this, basically I think you put it backwards by accident?)

Comment: Yes, it is $g\colon A\longrightarrow B$ and $f\colon B\longrightarrow\Bbb R$. My bad.